# MySQL ORDER BY first field then second field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

This is my actual query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT eventi.img AS img, posizione AS pos
    FROM eventi
    WHERE homepage =1
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT prodotti.img, prodotti.posizione
    FROM prodotti
    WHERE homepage =1 
    ORDER BY pos ASC
```

it returns positions like "1,1,2,2" . i want it returns positions by fields, like "event position 1,2 -> then products position 1,2" . Now it's mixing events and products  positions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT t.img,t.pos FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 1 as order_col, eventi.img AS img, posizione AS pos
    FROM eventi
    WHERE homepage =1
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT 2 , prodotti.img, prodotti.posizione
    FROM prodotti
    WHERE homepage =1 ) t
ORDER BY t.order_col,t.pos
```

If you don't care about selecting the `order_col` then you can avoid the sub select and put the order by inside.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), you have a union, and you need to take an extra step to ensure that `order by` clauses in the final query of the union apply to ALL of the queries, and not just that final query:

```
SELECT ...
UNION
SELECT ... ORDER     <--order final query only
```

v.s

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION
(SELECT ...) ORDER     <--order all queries as a single set
```

Note the extra `()`.

Comment: with `(SELECT DISTINCT eventi.img AS img, eventi.posizione AS pos
FROM eventi
WHERE homepage =1 ORDER BY pos ASC)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT prodotti.img, prodotti.posizione AS pos2
FROM prodotti
WHERE homepage =1 ORDER BY pos2 ASC)` i get now 1-2-2-1 ...